# Translate accented to unaccented characters in Sublime Text snippet using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, code-snippets, boost-regex

I'm writing a ST3 snippet that inserts a `\subsection{}` with a label. The label is created by converting the header text to conform with the [LaTeX standards for labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/what-are-the-valid-names-as-labels) using a (rather lengthy) regular expression:

```
${1/(?:([ \t_]+)?|\b)(?:([ÅÄÆÁÀÃ])?|\b)(?:([åäæâàáã])?|\b)(?:([ÉÈÊË])?|\b)(?:([éèëê])?|\b)(?:([ÌÌÎÏ])?|\b)(?:([íìïî])?|\b)(?:([Ñ])?|\b)(?:([ñ])?|\b)(?:([ÖØÓÒÔÖÕ])?|\b)(?:([öøóòôõ])?|\b)(?:([ÜÛÚÙ])?|\b)(?:([üûúù])?|\b)/(?1:-)(?2:A)(?3:a)(?4:E)(?5:e)(?6:I)(?7:i)(?8:N)(?9:n)(?10O)(?11:o)(?12:U)(?13:u)/g}
```

Actually, I would like for it to be even longer. But if I add the extra groups that I would like, then ST3 crashes when I execute the snippet.

```
${1/(?:([ \t_]+)?|\b)(?:([ÅÄÆÁÀÃ])?|\b)(?:([åäæâàáã])?|\b)(?:([Ç])?|\b)(?:([ç])?|\b)(?:([ÉÈÊË])?|\b)(?:([éèëê])?|\b)(?:([ÌÌÎÏ])?|\b)(?:([íìïî])?|\b)(?:([Ñ])?|\b)(?:([ñ])?|\b)(?:([ÖØÓÒÔÖÕ])?|\b)(?:([öøóòôõ])?|\b)(?:([ÜÛÚÙ])?|\b)(?:([üûúù])?|\b)(?:([Ý])?|\b)(?:([ÿý])?|\b)/(?1:-)(?2:A)(?3:a)(?4:C)(?5:c)(?6:E)(?7:e)(?8:I)(?9:i)(?10:O)(?11:o)(?12:N)(?13:n)(?14:U)(?15:u)(?16:Y)(?17:y)/g}
```

Is there any more efficient way of doing this? Preferably one that won't cause ST3 to crash ;)

**Edit:**
Here are some example strings:

```
Flygande bæckasiner søka hwila på mjuka tuvor
Åke Staël hade en överflödig idé
```

And the results (with the current, working regex):

```
Flygande-backasiner-soka-hwila-pa-mjuka-tuvor
Ake-Stael-hade-en-overflodig-ide
```

But I would like to also replace the characters (ÇçÝÿý) with their unaccented counterparts (CcYyy) so that e.g.

```
Comment ça va
```

becomes

```
Comment-ca-va
```

Comment: `(?:([ÅÄÆÁÀÃ])?|\b)` is an always true pattern because the first alternative can be empty, remove the useless `?` quantifier. Give several example strings and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this syntax, but I suspect that the problem comes from the too many optional groups combined with a lot of alternatives that cause a too complex processing.

So you can try to design your pattern like this, and you can add other groups of letters in the same way *(take a look at the unicode table to find character ranges)*:

```
${1/([ \t_]+)|([À-Å])|([à-å])|([È-Ë])|([è-ë])|([Ì-Ï])|([ì-ï])|([Ò-ÖØ])|([ò-öø])|([Ù-Ü])|([ù-ü])|(Æ)|(æ)|(Œ)|(œ)|(Ñ)|(ñ)/(?1:-)(?2:A)(?3:a)(?4:E)(?5:e)(?6:I)(?7:i)(?8:O)(?9:o)(?10:U)(?11:u)(?12:AE)(?13:ae)(?14:OE)(?15:oe)(?16:N)(?17:n)/g}
```

if the lookahead feature is available you can improve this pattern to prevent non-accented characters to be tested with each alternatives:

```
${1/(?=[ \t_À-ÆÈ-ÏÑ-ÖØ-Üà-æè-ïñ-öø-üŒœ])(?:([ \t_]+)|([À-Å])|([à-å])|([È-Ë])|([è-ë])|([Ì-Ï])|([ì-ï])|([Ò-ÖØ])|([ò-öø])|([Ù-Ü])|([ù-ü])|(Æ)|(æ)|(Œ)|(œ)|(Ñ)|(ñ))/(?1:-)(?2:A)(?3:a)(?4:E)(?5:e)(?6:I)(?7:i)(?8:O)(?9:o)(?10:U)(?11:u)(?12:AE)(?13:ae)(?14:OE)(?15:oe)(?16:N)(?17:n)/g}
```

Note: `Æ` *(Aelig)* must be transliterated as `AE` *(the same for `Œ` => `OE`)*